# Zellinhalt vs. Zelleninhalt regarding a cell of computer memory

Tags: noun, compound

Wenn es um den Inhalt einer Speicherzelle in einem Rechner geht, was ist korrekt bzgl. der deutschen Rechtschreibung: **Zellinhalt** oder **Zelleninhalt**?  Bitte eine sinnvolle Begründung mitangeben. Falls es einen Unterschied ausmacht, meine ich unter dem Inhalt einer Speicherzelle eher ein Maschinenwort als ein Bit.

Die Suchmaschinen haben natürlich ihre Vorlieben (z.B. [Zellinhalt](https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/com/0610041.htm), [Zelleninhalt](https://books.google.de/books?id=KjyDBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=Speicher+Zelleninhalt+Tabelle+Tabellenkalkulation+Tabellenkalkulationsprogramm+Excel&source=bl&ots=Yv6HU74T5m&sig=lRU43F2L5CW7XlvKcL3e5o1CyC0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBkoiN4N3dAhUPt4sKHXJMDYAQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Zelleninhalt&f=false)), und die kenne ich. Im Duden kommen sowohl *Zellinsasse* im Sinne eines Inhaftierten als auch *Zellinhalt* im biologischen Sinne vor. Wahrig kennt *Zellinhalt* im biologischen Sinne aber kennt *Zelleninhalt* gar nicht.  Aber all das sagt wenig über die Korrektheit aus.

Comment: Laut deutscher Rechtschreibung: Zelleninhalt.
Ich habe aber keine sinnvolle Erläuterung dafür.

Comment: Meinst du eine Speicherzelle oder eine Tabellenzelle ?

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/editing-help - bitte keine langen direkt-URLs. Danke.

Answer (score 4):

Aus meiner Intuition schöpfend, leider ohne eine Quelle nennen zu können, würde ich folgendes sagen:

*Zellinhalt* ist der Inhalt einer biologischen Zelle, analog zu *Zellsaft*, *Zellwand*, etc.

Den Inhalt einer Zelle in einem Rechner würde ich *Zelleninhalt* nennen. Ich denke, das ist die Bezeichnung, die in Excel verwendet wird, und da die Domäne "Elektronische Datenverarbeitung" die gemeinsame ist, scheint mir das naheliegend.

Answer (score 3):

Eine Suche bei *[ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zelleninhalt%2Czellinhalt&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CZelleninhalt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CZellinhalt%3B%2Cc0)* zeigt, dass *Zellinhalt* anscheinend moderner ist und in der Neuzeit überwiegt. Geht man allerdings die Suchergebnisse einzeln durch und vergleicht sie, findet man, dass sich **keine einzige** der Fundstellen auf den Inhalt einer Speicherzelle in einem Computer bezieht.

**Alle** Fundstellen aus dem IT-Bereich beziehen sich auf Zellen in einem Tabellenkalkulationsprogramm, die übrigen Fundstellen hauptsächlich auf biologische Sachverhalte. Der Begriff scheint für die Bezeichnung dessen, was du meinst, nicht verbreitet zu sein.

Daraus ergibt sich - Bevor ich mir einen Kopf machen würde, ob es *Zellinhalt* oder *Zelleninhalt* heißen muss, würde mir gut überlegen, ob ich nicht einen anderen Begriff wählen würde:

- Inhalt der Speicherzelle (wenn es denn unbedingt eine *Zelle sein muss*)
- Inhalt der Speicherstelle (scheint mir wesentlich gebräuchlicher)

oder ganz einfach

- das Bit (Byte, Wort,...)

Comment: Das stimmt *natürlich* - Für meine Suche auf ngrams, um die es in der Antwort ging.

Answer (score 3):

Der Inhalt einer Speicherzelle ist ein gespeicherter Wert, kann daher

> Speicherwert *(ein im Speicher befindlicher Wert)*

genannt werden, was meiner Ansicht nach besser passt als »Zell[en]inhalt«.

Analogon:

> [Katalogwert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Katalogwert) *(im Katalog von Ausstellungsstücken, Sammelobjekten
>   angegebener Wert eines Objektes )*

Comment: @user49915: Ja, ich halte das aber für einen eher selten vorkommenden Spezialfall.

Answer (score 1):

In Beziehung auf Speicherzellen sind beide Ausdrücke nicht wirklich angebracht. Das passt zwar für Tabellenkalkulation und Pflanzen, aber nicht für Computerspeicher, da es in dem Sinn keinen Inhalt gibt. Stattdessen speichert eine Speicherzelle lediglich einen **Zustand**, also entweder 1 oder 0.
Computerspeicher hat zwar Inhalt, aber die Information setzt sich aus den Zuständen einzelner Speicherzellen zusammen.

Comment: Das hängt von der Definition von „Zelle“ ab. Es handelt sich nicht um einen Begriff mit fester Bedeutung.